# Three "alias-functions" in my .bashrc file

Tags: beginner, bash

These functions work well for me. Can they be improved or made more standard in some way?

Each function has a documentation header block, which contains a description of what it does, along with example usage and reference links where applicable.

```
:<<COMMENT
    Alias function for recursive deletion, with are-you-sure prompt.
    Example call:
        srf /home/myusername/django_files/rest_tutorial/rest_venv/

    Short description: Stored in SRF_DESC

    With the following setting, this is *not* added to the history:
        export HISTIGNORE="*rm -r*:srf *"
    - http://superuser.com/questions/232885/can-you-share-wisdom-on-using-histignore-in-bash

    See:
    - y/n prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3232082/2736496
    - Alias w/param: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/2736496
COMMENT
#SRF_DESC: For "aliaf" command (with an 'F'). Must end with a newline.
SRF_DESC="srf [path]: Recursive deletion, with y/n prompt\n"
srf()  {
    #Actual line-breaks required in order to expand the variable.
    #- http://stackoverflow.com/a/4296147/2736496
    read -r -p "About to
sudo rm -rf $1
Are you sure? [y/N] " response
    response=${response,,}    # tolower
    if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y)$ ]]
    then
        echo -e "sudo rm -rf $1"
        sudo rm -rf "$1";
    else
        echo "Cancelled."
    fi
}
```

```
:<<COMMENT
    Delete item from history based on its line number. No prompt.

    Short description: Stored in HX_DESC

    Examples
        hx 112
        hx 3

    See:
    - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/how-to-delete-commands-in-history-matching-a-given-string
COMMENT
#HX_DESC: For "aliaf" command (with an 'F'). Must end with a newline.
HX_DESC="hx [linenum]: Delete history item at line number\n"
hx()  {
    history -d "$1";
}
```

```
:<<COMMENT
    Deletes all lines from the history that match a search string, with a
    prompt. The history file is then reloaded into memory.

    Short description: Stored in HXF_DESC

    Examples
        hxf "rm -rf"
        hxf ^source

    See:
    - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/how-to-delete-commands-in-history-matching-a-given-string
COMMENT
#HXF_DESC: For "aliaf" command (with an 'F'). Must end with a newline.
HXF_DESC="hxf [searchterm]: Delete all history items matching search term, with y/n prompt\n"
hxf()  {
    read -r -p "About to delete all items from history that match \"$1\". Are you sure? [y/N] " response
    response=${response,,}    # tolower
    if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y)$ ]]
    then
        #Delete all matched items from the file, and duplicate it to a temp
        #location.
        echo -e "grep -v \"$1\" \"$HISTFILE\" > /tmp/history"
        grep -v "$1" "$HISTFILE" > /tmp/history

        #Clear all items in the current sessions history (in memory). This
        #empties out $HISTFILE.
        echo "history -c"
        history -c

        #Overwrite the actual history file with the temp one.
        echo -e "mv /tmp/history \"$HISTFILE\""
        mv /tmp/history "$HISTFILE"

        #Now reload it.
        echo -e "history -r \"$HISTFILE\""
        history -r "$HISTFILE"     #Alternative: exec bash
    else
        echo "Cancelled."
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You never validate the contents/existence of `$1`

  - for instance: `grep -v "" "$HISTFILE"` returns nothing, so you're deleting your entire history.
- You might want to use `set -x`, `set +x` instead of `echo`-ing the commands about to be done.

Answer (score 4):

@GlennJackman already pointed out the biggest problems.
A few minor points:

- I don't see much purpose of the `-e` flag of the `echo` statements: *"enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes"*. If you really need this functionality it would be better to use `printf` instead, as that's more portable and a good practice. Or if you don't need the `-e`, then just drop it.
- In some places you have trailing `;` on lines, for example `sudo rm -rf "$1";`